# jquery dynamically split string and wrap into class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to split the div's text and add class to the second string. But no luck :(

Here's the code:

```
<div class="graphTooltipText">925 11:45pm</div>
```

This is not working:

```
  var str = $( ".graphTooltipText" ).html();
  var splitter = str.split(' ')[1];
  $(splitter).wrap('<div class="time" />');
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap it and then update the original element, so try

```
$('.graphTooltipText').html(function (i, html) {
    return html.replace(/\s(.*$)/, ' <div class="time">$1</div>')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/F5S4R/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/kJm8Q/1/

This simply wraps the item, and spits out the 2nd array element:

```
$(".graphTooltipText").wrap(function() {
    $(this).html("<div class='time'>" + $( this ).text().split(" ")[1] + "</div>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    var str = $(".graphTooltipText").html(function (_, html) {
        return html.replace(html.split(' ')[1], '<div class="time" >' + html.split(' ')[1] + '</div>');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it too:

```
var str = $(".graphTooltipText").text();
var splitter = str.split(' ');

var timeDiv = $('<div/>', {
   'class': 'time',
   text: splitter[1] // put the time here
});

$(".graphTooltipText").html(splitter[0]).append(timeDiv); // update the div content
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/249aq/)